# Downloading a file via PHP script results in wrong/different md5 checksum - why?

Tags: php, download, md5

I'm trying to implement an indirect download through PHP. On the client side I verify if the downloaded file is correct or not using md5.

When I download the file directly (http://server/folder/file.apk) I get the same md5 checksum as on the file system, but when I download it via the PHP script (http://server/some_page.php) I get a totally different checksum. Why?

Here's my PHP script:

```
<?php
$name_file="test2.apk";
$path="/home/user/public_html/apk/"; 
$dimension_file=(string)filesize($name_file);

header("Content-Type: application/vnd.android.package-archive ; name=".$name_file);
header("Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary");
header("Content-Length: ".$dimension_file);
header("Content-Disposition: inline; filename=".$name_file);
header("Expires: 0");
header("Cache-Control: no-cache, must-revalidate");
header("Cache-Control: private");
header("Pragma: public");

readfile($path.$name_file);
?>
```

Comment: Check for white spaces in the code and remove them. Mostly by indenting. Also it's a good practice not to close the php with ?> when executing code that isn't directly writing something on the page.

Comment: Make sure there are no newlines or spaces before the `<?php` or after the `?>`.  It's also a good idea to `exit;` after sending the file, just to be safe.

Comment: You may check the encoding, for example UTF-8 on one side and ISO on the other. If your php script is not in the same encoding, it can result on some checksum errors

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the error:

```
 $name_file="test2.apk";
 $path="/home/user/public_html/apk/"; 
 $dimension_file=(string)filesize($name_file); //<-- HERE! ---
```

i was retrieving the size using only the name of file instead of using the full path

```
filesize($name_file) ---> filesize( $path . $name_file)
```

the error was hidden from

```
header("Content-Type: application/vnd.android.package-archive");
```

and the php error response added to the content of the downloaded file.

So i suggest to who has this kind of problems to comment the "Content-Type" while debugging to see if there are some errors in the php code and when all code seems to work re-enable the "Content-Type" header.

On my server spaces in the code before the

```
readfile($path.$name_file);
```

has no influence on the checksum

Thanks to Vladimir and Rocket for good practice tips

Answer (score 0):

I was having similar problems downloading PDF files, via an fread (although readfile gave the same problem). My eventual problem was solved by turning off the debug output of the application - which in my case was [Wordpress](http://wordpress.org). I had WP_DEBUG set to true which caused the differences in MD5.